# Invalid UTF-8 Character during loading, but HOW?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import config
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


username = config.username
dbpassword = config.dbpassword
dbhost = config.dbtesturl
infrabi = config.infraBIURL
infrabipassword = config.infrabipassword
connCobra =  pymysql.connect(host=dbhost, port=3306,user=username,password=dbpassword,db='dcgsreports',autocommit=True,local_infile=1)
engine = create_engine('postgresql://%s:%s@%s:8192/dcometrics?client_encoding=utf8' %(username, infrabipassword, infrabi))

extractQuery = '''<snipped query as it seems to cause confusion>'''

path = '//unc.path.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/Test/'            
csvFile = 'Invoices.csv'

df = pd.read_sql_query(extractQuery,engine)
df.to_csv(path+csvFile,sep=",", index=False, encoding="utf-8")

tableName = csvFile.split('.')[0]

truncQuery = '''TRUNCATE TABLE %s''' %tableName
loadQuery = '''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s%s' INTO TABLE dcgsreports.%s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;''' %(path, csvFile, tableName)
cursor = connCobra.cursor()
cursor.execute(truncQuery)
cursor.execute(loadQuery)
connCobra.close()
```

Okay a couple of things first:

1. I didn't write the query, it was written years ago by someone else.  I am merely transferring it.
2. I don't own the postgres database the query is coming out of, so changes there are unlikely to impossible.

I don't understand how pandas is grabbing a sql_query as a string (I assume) and then saving a csv as utf-8 with an invalid character.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-582b9b13574f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Python-Scripts/Invoices.py', wdir='D:/Python-Scripts')

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Python-Scripts/Invoices.py", line 91, in <module>
    cursor.execute(loadQuery)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
    result.read()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1071, in read
    self._read_load_local_packet(first_packet)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1123, in _read_load_local_packet
    ok_packet = self.connection._read_packet()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)

InternalError: (1300, "Invalid utf8 character string: '180529055'")
```

It is failing as it attempts to load it to an Aurora 5.7.12 database and I can't understand why.

Is there something else I need to be doing to the csv file before I attempt to load it?  I tried stripping any non-utf-8 characters and get the same error.

Comment: It's hard to tell what line of your long program is causing this error to be thrown,  that would be the most important thing to nail down because it looks like the error happens in PyMySQL, and not anything to do with Pandas of CSV files. I'd guess the problem was in `cursor.execute(truncQuery)` or `cursor.execute(loadQuery)` because of this line in the stack trace: `"D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute`.

Comment: Yes, it is throwing the error when it attempts to load it to the Aurora 5.7.12 database because the database kicks back an error that flags a non-utf-8 character string.  What that means is that when the CSV is being made with utf-8 encoding it is not doing it properly for some reason and I have no idea how that is possible since I told it to use UTF-8 encoding.  Additionally, if you remove the query itself the program is rather short.

Comment: I snipped the extract query so it doesn't look as daunting.

Comment: So what's `tableName`?

Comment: ummmm what?  csvFile is set to Invoices.csv... so tablename would be Invoices.

Comment: removing encoding='utf-8' from the csv creation results in the same error; I am wondering if the encoding is not working or if I need to do something else to strip non-utf-8 characters before I create the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import config
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


username = config.username
dbpassword = config.dbpassword
dbhost = config.dbtesturl
infrabi = config.infraBIURL
infrabipassword = config.infrabipassword
connCobra =  pymysql.connect(host=dbhost, port=3306,user=username,password=dbpassword,db='dcgsreports',autocommit=True,local_infile=1)
engine = create_engine('postgresql://%s:%s@%s:8192/dcometrics?client_encoding=utf8' %(username, infrabipassword, infrabi))

extractQuery = '''<snipped query as it seems to cause confusion>'''

path = '//unc.path.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/Test/'            
csvFile = 'Invoices.csv'

df = pd.read_sql_query(extractQuery,engine)
df.to_csv(path+csvFile,sep=",", index=False, encoding="utf-8")

tableName = csvFile.split('.')[0]

truncQuery = '''TRUNCATE TABLE %s''' %tableName
loadQuery = '''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s%s' CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 INTO TABLE dcgsreports.%s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;''' %(path, csvFile, tableName)
cursor = connCobra.cursor()
cursor.execute(truncQuery)
cursor.execute(loadQuery)
connCobra.close()
```

Adding CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 to the load query has allowed the load and fixed it, but I am still not sure why there was a problem to begin with, but fixed is fixed.